# S3 React Typescript not uploading file even though response is 200

Tags: reactjs, typescript, amazon-s3

I have the following state set in React:

```
    const [idDocument, setIDDocument] = useState<File>(null);
```

now after the user adds this idDocument PDF file, it is stored in the state.
Now I use this package: https://github.com/NimperX/react-aws-s3-typescript

Also when I log the idDocument file I get a proper File object.
Here I use the uploadFile method and add the document like this:

```
    const s3 = new ReactS3Client({
         ...s3Config,
    });

    const filename = 'myfile';

    try {
         const res = await s3.uploadFile(idDocument, filename);

         console.log(res);
    } catch (exception) {
         console.log(exception);
    }
```

The S3Config looks like this and it seems to connect properly.

```
export const s3Config = {
   bucketName:  '...',
   region: '...',
   accessKeyId:'...',
   secretAccessKey: '...',
   s3Url: '...'
}
```

My response is this:

```
{
   bucket: "...", 
   key: ".../myfile.pdf", 
   location: "the_real_url", 
   status: 200
}
```

But now no matter what I do I can't see the file in AWS S3.

Comment: This is unlikely. Double check the bucket name.

Comment: Checked it and it still doesn't upload sadly.
I can use the s3Url like this right: 'https://s3.console.aws.amazon.com/s3/buckets/xxxxxxxxx'

and the bucket name is just the name that is in the url and just the normal name of the bucket right?

Comment: I have fixed it, had some permission and base url issues.